# How to right-justify elements in a list?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I need my func to print out the following:

```
  apples Alice  dogs
 oranges   Bob  cats
cherries Carol moose
  banana David goose
```

all items are aligned to the right

and I have solution but it's kinda workaround, could you please help me to correct my solution?

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def printData(lst):
  colWidths = [0] * len(tableData)

  for a in range(len(tableData)):
    colWidths[a] = len(max(tableData[a], key=len))

  for i in range(len(lst[0])):
    output = ''
    for j in range(len(lst)):
      output += (str(lst[j][i])).rjust(colWidths[0])
    print(output)


print(printData(tableData))

  apples   Alice    dogs
 oranges     Bob    cats
cherries   Carol   moose
  banana   David   goose
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) together with `str.format`

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

for tup in zip(*tableData):
    print("{:>9} {:>9} {:>9}".format(*tup))
```

prints

```
   apples     Alice      dogs
  oranges       Bob      cats
 cherries     Carol     moose
   banana     David     goose
```

EDIT:

You can generate these strings dynamically, if you don't know what size you want the columns when you write the code

```
from itertools import chain

def gen_format_str(widths):
    return ' '.join(["{{:>{}}}".format(width) for width in widths])

def n_of_width(n, width):
    return gen_format_str([width] * n)

def all_widest(list_of_lists):
    return n_of_width(len(list_of_lists), max(map(len, chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))))

format_str = all_widest(tableData)

for tup in zip(*tableData):
    print(format_str.format(*tup))
```

`format_str` is `'{:>8} {:>8} {:>8}'`, because the longest word, "cherries" is 8 characters long.

Comment: beat me for a second

Comment: but how to know that 9 is enough?

Comment: @nikkitikitavi You don't.  I'll include a way to dynamically generate these format strings based on some criteria.

Comment: @nikkitikitavi see my edit. Play around with the format language, it's pretty powerful, and less complicated than the docs make it appear.  Chack out https://pyformat.info/, the tutorial there is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

```
for index in range(len(tableData)):
```

is wrong about 80% of the time. Try it first with `for a in mylist` or with `for index,a in enumerate(mylist)`. That is usually a simpler approach.

In this case:

```
>>> tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
>>> fruits, persons, pets = tableData
>>> for n,fruit in enumerate(fruits):
        print (f"{fruit:>8s} {persons[n]:>8s} {pets[n]:>8s}")
  apples    Alice     dogs
 oranges      Bob     cats
cherries    Carol    moose
  banana    David    goose
```

But that doesn't handle scaling the column widths to take the least amount of space needed. To include that refinement, compute the column widths and include them in the formatting:

```
>>> widths = [max(len(x) for x in d) for d in tableData]
>>> for n,fruit in enumerate(fruits):
        print (f"{fruit:>{widths[0]}s} {persons[n]:>{widths[1]}s} {pets[n]:>{widths[2]}s}")

  apples Alice  dogs
 oranges   Bob  cats
cherries Carol moose
  banana David goose
```